# remove systemd service in yocto?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I want to remove a systemd service 'timesyncd' for a **test-image1** where as keep the same service for another image **test-image2**. The first image runs on 0x86 arch and the second runs on ARM. For removing the **timesyncd**, I have created a systemd_%.bbappend file and added this line:

> > PACKAGECONFIG_remove = "timesyncd"

This works fine just for removing it, but how can I remove the service in one image and keep it in another. Is there some sort of if else inside bitbake or can we create two bbappend file to achieve this?

Comment: The usual approach is to create a debug-`DISTRO` that modifies whatever needed. You cannot do this from a recipe (also not an image one).

Comment: @LetoThe2nd can you provide a simple example

Comment: Since it's for different machines, I think you could use `PACKAGECONFIG_remove_<yourmachinename> = "timesyncd"`.

Comment: Thinking more about it, you are building for two machine. just drop something like `PACKAGECONFIG_machinea_remove = "timesyncd"` in your distro file. Or without the `machinea`-part in the MACHINE config file. Thats not exactly clean, but depending on the usecase can be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @LetThe2nd and @Erik Botö.

There are severall OVERRIDES possible in yocto, to use the MACHINEOVERRIDES in your bbapend file to remove an package from PACKAGECONFIG:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_remove_<MACHINETYPE> = "<package-to-remove>"
```

[OVERRIDES](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-OVERRIDES)